# Can't authenticate via ssh key on new GitLab container

Tags: ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I've recently set up a new GitLab docker container, and though everything else has been working great I can't authenticate to it via ssh.

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) to the letter, with no succes.
Whatever key type I generate, and regardless of the client (Linux, Windows git-bash), The server instantly rejects the publickey and does not prompt for a password.

Debug shows the following:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519   SHA256:[SHA-256]
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

Maybe it's something obvious, but I can't quite figure it out and no troubleshooting step managed to help.
As a side note, the ssh port is non standard, though I am accesing via the new port. I've also double checked ssh is enabled on both the server and the clients.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is similar to [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 18371](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/18371#note_24242847) "docker omnibus gitlab denying ssh public key"

> In my case the problem was mismatch between ssh socket that docker container was exposing and my server's one.
> It helped to expose it on different port like `10022` and reconfiguring gitlab like this:
>
> ```
> gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 10022
> ```

Ideally, you would need to stop, restart the ssh daemon (server side, container side as seen [in this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ci-runner-ssh-ssh-handshake-failed-ssh-unable-to-authenticate/8367/2)) with

```
usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

That would allow you to check:

- if the SSH request is received at all
- if it is blocked for any reason